# issue with ImageButton(cant change the background)

Tags: android, imagebutton

```
int num++;
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card +num);
```

my pictures are in the drawable folder and they are ok!
the problem is that i cant use R.drawable.card_1 !
how can i solve this!?

i've already tried the code below

```
int num++;
img.setBackfroundResource("R.drawable.card_"+num);
```

but its not working either!

one of my pictures name is card_1 to card_10
i want when user clicked on Next button the next picture comes!

Comment: please, not again ...

Comment: what is this?? not again what?

Comment: this question was asked bazillion time ... name what you wana achive then  use google

Comment: i could'nt find any topic! thats why i started this

Comment: @Gérson Mendes de Souza answered me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("card_"+num, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: wow thanks can u tell me how does this works?? tnx